# Enemy Projectile Script Won't Shoot Closest Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I Have been trying to figure out how the Enemy doesn't return multiple GameObjects it only returns one.Im not sure whether it is my Bullet script that it allows only one object to return. I'm currently trying to develop a Game with multiple players like Slither.io so I'm not sure if the performance is affected I would like to use (List Function) but dont know where to start and I'm using a later version Unity 2017.3.1f1. Much Appreciated for your help.The scripts are below.

```
public class RandomAIProjectile
{
    private GameObject[] target;
    
    public float speed;
    
    Rigidbody2D bulletRB;
    
    public GameObject explosionEffect;
    
    // Find Targets Section.
    void Start () 
    {
        if (target == null)
            target = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < target.Length; i++) 
        {
            bulletRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
            
            Vector2 moveDir = (target[i].transform.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;
            
            bulletRB.velocity = new Vector2 (moveDir.x, moveDir.y);
            
            Destroy (this.gameObject, 2);
        }
        
    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        // Decoy Script To Destroy Players.
        if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<BlackthronpodDiePlayer>() != null)
        {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
            Destroy (gameObject); 
        }
        // Damage Effect.
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
            Instantiate (explosionEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        // Player (Bullet) Destroy Enemy.
        if (other.CompareTag ("Bullet"))
        {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
            Destroy (gameObject); 
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Here is the Player Script

```
public class RandomAIEnemy
{
    //Random Movement
    
    public float speed;
    
    public float waitTime;
    
    public float startWaitTime;
    
    public Transform moveSpots;
    
    public float minX;
    public float minY;
    
    public float maxX;
    public float maxY;
    
    //Enemy AI Shooting 
    
    public float lineOfSite;
    
    public float shootingRange;
    
    public float fireRate = 1f;
    
    private float nextFireTime;
    
    public GameObject bullet;
    
    public GameObject bulletParent;

    // My Current Player
    private BlackthronpodPlayerX playerX;

    // Player AI
    private GameObject[] player;

    public GameObject blood;
    
    Vector3 respawn = new Vector3 (-34f,0,0);
    
    //Additional Info
    
    
    void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        EnemyS ();
    }
    
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        //My Player AI Tag.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        
        waitTime = startWaitTime;

        //My Current Player Tag.
        playerX = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").GetComponent<BlackthronpodPlayerX>();

        //Random Movement Reference
        moveSpots.position = new Vector2 (Random.Range (minX, maxX), Random.Range (minY, maxY));
    }


     //Closest (My Player Including Player AI.)
    private bool TryGetClosestPlayer(out GameObject closest)
    {
        var playersSortedByDistance = player.OrderBy(p => ((Vector2)p.transform.position - (Vector2)transform.position).sqrMagnitude);
        closest = playersSortedByDistance.FirstOrDefault();
        return closest;
    }

    
    void EnemyS () 
    {
        GameObject closestPlayer = null;
        
        if(TryGetClosestPlayer (out closestPlayer))
        {
            var distanceFromPlayer = Vector2.Distance (closestPlayer.transform.position, transform.position);
            
            if (distanceFromPlayer <= shootingRange && nextFireTime < Time.time) 
            {
                Instantiate (bullet, bulletParent.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                
                nextFireTime = Time.time + fireRate;
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Range And Shooting Boundary For Player Including Player AI.
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected () 
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position, lineOfSite);
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position, shootingRange);
        
    }
    
    // Random Movement (I).
    void RandomMove () 
    {
        //Rotate Movement Of Enemy.
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, moveSpots.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        
        if (Vector2.Distance (transform.position, moveSpots.position) < 0.2f)
            
        {
            if(waitTime <= 0)
            {   
                moveSpots.position = new Vector2 (Random.Range (minX, maxX), Random.Range (minY, maxY));
                waitTime = startWaitTime;
                
            } else {
                
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
                
            }
        }
    }
    
        
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        // Damage Effect On Enemy.
        if (collision.gameObject.tag.Equals ("Player")) 
        {
            Instantiate(blood,transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        }

        // My Players Health.
        if (collision.CompareTag ("Player")) 
        {
            playerX.health --;
            Debug.Log(playerX.health);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        // Player Score Manager.
        if (collision.tag == "Bullet")
        {
            Game.AddToScore(1);
            
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your code is pretty confusing.  So you seem to pick players only when spawned.  But im sure if you add some debug statements to see what values are where you will find the answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have **Rigidbody2d** attached on your enemy and player. And also, is there any error coming in the code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am not sure where is he getting stuck, where is the error coming or what are his expectations with the code he has written? If you could have given the option to comment and clarify these doubts then this problem wouldn’t have occurred. Hope so you understand.

Comment: Where I'm getting stuck is that my EnemyAi only shoots one object (Player) and never shoots again even when it comes to the nearest my EnemyAi shoots the first Player spawned, whilst there are other players within the Shooting Range. I'll admit my code is pretty messy

Comment: This is happening because after the AI has shot and destroyed the player then there is no gameObject named as 'Player' so it will return null. Make the code go in a loop to solve the problem.

Comment: Loop , How do I use this function , it's quite new to me... 

Comment: Loop isn’t any kind of a function but it is a sequence of instructions that are repeated multiple times until a certain or special condition is reached or until the processor can support it. You can use a for, foreach and while loop to keep the statements repeating themselves.

Comment: I'll look into it Thank You.

Comment: Ummm sorry how do I loop the code exactly 